# Input pattern validation - More than one pattern

Tags: regex, html, validation, input

I've been using the input type inside a form in HTML and using the pattern attribute in order to better validate the data entry.

Is there a way to permit more than one pattern in a single input type?

For instance, I'd like to permit both `[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{8}` and `d{8}\[a-zA-Z]{1}`

This would be one of the inputs I've used so far but as you can see I have there just one pattern:

```
<input type="text" id="txtID" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1}\d{8}" required/>
```

It might be possible that since my knowledge of RegEx is limited there might be a way to use a RegEx formula that permits boths patterns but I really don't know.

Comment: I've posted them on the question :). They are supposed to mean 1 char and 8 numbers or 8 numbers and 1 char.

Comment: Use alternation: `[a-zA-Z]\d{8}|d{8}[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: I KNEW there would be a way to do it using RegEx; Argh.... thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation operator `|` to allow alternative patterns:

```
[a-zA-Z]\d{8}|d{8}[a-zA-Z]
```

Note that you do not need to add any anchors or grouping, see [*pattern* documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/common-input-element-attributes.html):

> This implies that the regular expression language used for this attribute is the same as that used in JavaScript, except that the pattern attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end).